# Effective database usage

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I've started working on a new application, its supposed to be scalable.

There are Companies, each company has Leads.
I want my Front End to display the amount of Leads a company has each month.

What would be more efficient in the long run:
Running table cross-reference and counting the amount of leads with "Date Added" and "CompanyID"
or 
creating a separate table with a counter and update it each time a new Lead is added?

Answer (score 0):

Of course storing the counter will be more efficient, but the question is: is it worth it? You need to make your decision basing on the scale of your project.

Also, another option is to use [cache](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache) to separate logic behind storing value that normally would be calculated.